# Server code is not firing when calling from client using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, http, post

I am trying to call a server side method from the client using jQuery ajax.  The server method never fires or throws an error.  It simply does nothing.  I am using .NET version 4.6.1.  The project was created using Visual Studio 2017 and the project template used was "ASP.NET Web Forms Site".  I got most of the client code from searching Stack Overflow.  I got multiple hits on my issue but none seem to work.  I also tried a simple jQuery call by giving a div an id and hiding it, i.e. `$("#test").hide();`. That test call worked fine so I am reasonably sure that jQuery itself is working. I also tried the server method code inside the `Page_Load` method and it worked.

Here is my client code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/SayHello",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert('success');
    }

</script>

<div class="row">
    <h1>AJAX Test</h1>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Here is my server code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static void SayHello()
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\WriteText.txt", "hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the status is 200 according to the F12 developer tools in IE.

Comment: Sorry, missed the second part of your comment.  It says: {"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

Comment: Add that to your question. That's the kind of thing you should check yourself before posting, and make sure to include vital details like that in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  I did not realize the F12 tools had the ability to view the body until you mentioned it.